# Need to understand this program from python book

Tags: python, oop

I am reading the Python Cookbook and they have this program there:

```
class Temperature(object):
    coefficients = {'c': (1.0, 0.0, -273.15), 'f': (1.8, -273.15, 32.0),
                    'r': (1.8, 0.0, 0.0)}


    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # default to absolute (Kelvin) 0, but allow one named argument,
        # with name being k, c, f or r, to use any of the scales
        try:
            name, value = kwargs.popitem( )
        except KeyError:
            # no arguments, so default to k=0
            name, value = 'k', 0
        # error if there are more arguments, or the arg's name is unknown
        if kwargs or name not in 'kcfr':
            kwargs[name] = value             # put it back for diagnosis
            raise TypeError, 'invalid arguments %r' % kwargs
        setattr(self, name, float(value))


    def __getattr__(self, name):
        # maps getting of c, f, r, to computation from k
        try:
            eq = self.coefficients[name]
        except KeyError:
            # unknown name, give error message
            raise AttributeError, name
        return (self.k + eq[1]) * eq[0] + eq[2]


    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        # maps settings of k, c, f, r, to setting of k; forbids others
        if name in self.coefficients:
            # name is c, f or r -- compute and set k
            eq = self.coefficients[name]
            self.k = (value - eq[2]) / eq[0] - eq[1]
        elif name == 'k':
            # name is k, just set it
            object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
        else:
            # unknown name, give error message
            raise AttributeError, name

    def __str__(self):
        # readable, concise representation as string
        return "%s K" % self.k


    def __repr__(self):
        # detailed, precise representation as string
        return "Temperature(k=%r)" % self.k
```

I didn't understand the following - could someone help me to do so?:

1. what does this function do `name, value = kwargs.popitem( )`
2. What does `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` do. He didn't used these in the final calling of the program

This was the ouput:

```
>>> from te import Temperature
>>> t = Temperature(f=70)        # 70 F is...
>>> print t.c                    # ...a bit over 21 C
21.1111111111
>>> t.c = 23                     # 23 C is...
>>> print t.f                    # ...a bit over 73 F
73.4
```

Comment: [http://codereview.stackexchange.com/](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) ?

Comment: @FlorinGhita CodeReview isn't for explaining code from books.

Comment: @LevLevitsky you're right, should be own code.

Comment: Not quite sure what's trying to be shown in this "Cookbook Example" - but seems over elaborate instead of just writing `__init__` taking a single parameter of `scale` which then just does a try on the class's coefficients and raises a `TypeError` (which I think should be a `ValueError` anyway)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The [`kwargs.popitem()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.popitem) removes *one* (arbitrary) item from the `kwargs` dictionary and returns that as a `(key, value)` tuple. This is then assigned to two variables, `name` and `value`.

  In this case it means the class takes *one* keyword argument (one of `k`, `f`, `c` or `r`) and if you specify more than one it'll complain (throw a `TypeError`) after having looked at *one* of the keyword arguments you passed in.
- [`__getattr__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) and [`__setattr__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__) are special methods used by python when [looking up attributes](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access).

  `t.c` translates to `t.__getattr__('c')`, and `t.c = 23` translates to `t.__setattr__('c', 23)`.

  So, setting one of `t.c`, `t.f` or `t.r` to an integer is routed to the `__setattr__` method, which then uses the `self.coefficients` mapping to calculate and set `self.k` instead.

  Looking up one of `t.c`, `t.f` or `t.r` is routed to the `__getattr__` method, which then returns a value based on the `self.coefficients` mapping together with the existing value of `self.k` to give you a temperature in the requested scale.

Comment: Would an upvote help? :)

Comment: @JonClements: Ask me in an hour. :-)

Comment: @JonClements I really doubt that :) [It looks](http://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters?tab=reputation&sort=graph) like Martijn doesn't stop even after the rep cap :)